# Get reference to stdin file descriptor of Node.js process, must work on MacOS too

Tags: shell-script, osx, node.js

On a Linux machine, if I have the pid of a process, I can write to the stdin of that process using something like:

```
/proc/<pid>/fd/0
```

but on MacOS, this doesn't appear possible. I am told that I should use `mkfifo` / named pipes.

However using named pipes is making the problem harder to solve. Is there a way on MacOS to store a reference to a fd on the filesystem if you control the start of the process?

For example, if I do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
node script.js &
NODEJS_PID=$!
```

I can easily get the pid of this process, represented above by the NODEJS_PID var. However, is there a way to capture a reference to the file descriptor of the stdin to this nodejs process?

If I can get the path to the fd that would be cool, because I need to write to that fd from another process altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Since you know the PID on OS X, `lsof` might work for you:

```
lsof -p 12345 | awk '$4=="0u"{print $NF}'
/dev/ttys039
# then you can write to the FD
echo "hi" > /dev/ttys039
```

Comment: thanks can you comment on the lsof line and let people know what it does?

Comment: `lsof` lists the open files on a system. The `-p` option lists open files for a particular process id.

Comment: just curious, how do you know this is the fd for stdin?

Comment: @AlexanderMills But note that the example shown doesn't actually do what you want. If you write to a terminal, that displays the text on the terminal, it doesn't feed input to a program that's reading from the terminal. This goes whether you refer to the terminal directly through its `/dev` entry or via a Linux magic link under `/proc/$pid/fd`. It works with a pipe because pipes aren't bidirectional.

Comment: I think I follow what you are saying Gilles, so mkfifo is really the best way to do this?

Comment: Indeed, the example doesn't help with your main question, as the input won't be fed to a program reading from the terminal.